# Google maps displays black screen when trying to navigate

Tags: google-maps, htc-one-x

When getting directions to a new place on Google maps (using navigate) I get a black screen where the map tile should be.

Sometimes after a few seconds, Maps force closes and I have to type the place again.

It takes me about 4 or 5 attempts to get it working.

I have tried:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling Google Maps
- Clearing cache
- Clearing data
- Factory reset
- Different ROM

Here are some screenshots of the issue:

[image: click for larger image]
[image: click for larger image]

Comment: Have you installed latest version?

Comment: Of course, I have been experiencing the same issue for a few versions though.

Comment: Screenshots would be welcome :-)

Comment: I'll update as soon as I can get some :)

Comment: Does this issue happen only when navigating or also when generally using Maps? Does the problem change if viewing the map using satellite mode?

Comment: Its only when navigating, and it still happens in satellite mode

Comment: Is your GPS working properly? Can you try [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cochibo.gpsstatus) and report back.

Comment: Tested and GPS works fine

Comment: I've updated the question with screenshots that I grabbed yesterday. Any ideas would be appreciated!